# How many elements of a given character vector contain more than one word

Tags: r, count

I am supposed to write a function to compute how many elements of a given character vector contain more than one word. The data set "state.name" gives the names of 50 US states: how many of these consist of several words? So far i got to this

```
state.name 
sapply(gregexpr("\\S+", state.name), length)
```

Now i would like to count the number of 2 which appeared.

Comment: You could do `sum(v1==2)` if `v1 <- sapply(....)` or use `table(v1>1)`. Another option would be `str_count` from `stringr`

Comment: Does it have to be in base R?

Comment: What about `sum(grepl("\\s", state.name))`